# Android In App Billing Commit to Pay at a Later Time?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing

I've got a concept for an Android application that I would like to develop.  However, after much research I'm still unsure if a vital component of the app is supported with the android in app billing system and hoped that maybe someone shared a similar issue in the past.

Basically, I'm hoping to ask the user to commit to buying an in app item at a later time if an event does not occur.  Therefore I'd hoped that I could suspend the payment until that later time and then execute this payment if the said event does not occur.

Is one able to suspend payments until a later time and cancel them if some event does occur, but execute the payment if not?

Comment: Isn't it usually the opposite. Provide a free app until an event, such as requesting the app not show ads anymore, happens - the user pays then loads an alternative version of the app?

Comment: BobbyDigital - typically this is the case.  However, the concept I have in mind works the way I've tried to explain (although probably poorly) above.

Comment: Yes but you're being secretive and obscure. Complicating things usually complicates things; duh right? The whole premise is a bit weird. I'm going to give you the app for free with an expectation to be paid later - but only if you **don't** do something! If you do said event it's free. Having trouble understanding that model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could delay the presentation of the in-app billing process until that "later date"--and hope the user went through with it on faith. Regardless, they could cancel the purchase anyway if they weren't happy with the (blackmail) scenario, so you have nothing to lose!

Comment: Yes. I think this is an alternative.  I was hoping to find a "documented" solution to the on faith problem.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have the user click "purchase," store that in preferences, then on whatever event should cause a "commit" state present your in-app billing sequence.

Comment: Can the in-app billing sequence occur at the start of the "purchase" stage upon user click/commit and then behind the scenes either payment gets cancelled or executed at the later date/time given the outcome of an independent event?

Comment: No. I think you would just have to make it look as if that had happened, (Dialog: "Thank you for your purchase, your credit card will not be billed unless X happens"), then consume when X actually occurs. At which point they can opt out of the purchase.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. Google Play In-App Billing only offers three types of products: Managed, Unmanaged, and Subscription.

Comment: It is definitely true that there are three types of products.  What I'd hope to do is have the user commit to purchasing a managed product at a later date and time if an event does not transpire within the application.

Comment: I don't think that is possible, nor have I seen it implemented. You would be best off just adding the user to a list of those who want the item at a later date, and then notify them when it becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can define your trial period after that time the payment will be occur. It can be done by Selecting **Subscription**. It will ask credientials at first but charge payment at later time. In the mean while you can cancel your purchase at any time.